# Send event between two Parse.com Swift apps

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, parse-platform, qr-code

I am building a simple QR-code scanning system in Swift using Parse as my backend. I have built one app that scans a QR-code, and thereafter updates it to "active = false".

I have also built a separate app that generates new QR-codes for the first app to scan. I want to enable the second app to generate a new QR-code to display once the first app has scanned the current one.

One way I think I could solve this would be by constantly (with an interval) query parse.com to check if the object has changed (has been updated from "active = true" to "active = false"), but this would mean that I have to send a lot of unnecessary queries to parse, which will be costly (as there is a limit to how many queries you can send for free).

Is there any other way I can let my second app know that the first app has scanned the QR-code?

All help is much appreciated!

Comment: That's just what push is for.  Not sure I understand the details of your app, but any app that wants to know when a state change happens can subscribe to a channel for that state change.  When the state change happens (a nice place to catch that is on afterSave of the object that keeps the state), push to that channel.  The payload of the push can even be empty.  The apps that get the push know that they should read the newly changed state from the backend.